# Can't open office documents from SharePoint site

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ms-word, ms-office, office365

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and some users, I'll repeat, only SOME of them can't open office files in their client application (word, excel...). I don't know what is the problem because I can open documents from my machine but when I log in to another machine (colleague that can't open documents) I'm also unable to open documents. So, problem is in machine. I tried:

- removing office cache files
- Adding SharePoint site to Trusted zone
- Repairing office installation...

Nothing helps. Message after a longer period of "downloading": Sorry, we couldn't find . It is possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
Sometimes there is an another message...

Comment: Have you checked that their default browser is IE?  SharePoint  often has compatibility problems with Other browsers.

Comment: Yes we tried IE 8,9, chrome, firefox, same problem..We also tried reseting IE options...

Comment: Do the machines that don't work have both Office 2013 and 2010 installed?  Are you trying to open files in Office 2013?

Comment: I doubt that this can be a problem. One machine had Office 2013 installed but now it has Office 2010.. Even this creates problem it is a very big bug for Microsoft. ULS does not show anything useful to

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Problem is solved by installing newest updates (from 5. December 2015. to 15. December 2015.). I'm not sure but probably this update solved problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3023068

Thanks everyone for support

Answer (score -1):

Look at your installed Windows updates.  If you have KB3055034, uninstall it and see if that helps - worked for us!

Comment: That update is not installed.. Is there any other update that can create a problem? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The solution we found that worked like a charm was deleting the counters.dat file out of the user's Temporary Internet Files. Please see the steps below:

1. Close all instances of IE and other browsers
2. Delete counters.dat file (location: \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\ )
3. Reopen IE or other browser

This worked like a charm and has been a big help with other tough fixes like plugin issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help but Microsoft Update solved this problem a few months ago :)