# Unable to edit sharepoint 2013 documents in the browser and application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am unable to edit the **sharepoint 2013** documents in the browser or the application. This is occurring in all the sites under the farm.

**Browser:**
It opens perfectly but is non editable

**Application:**
It opens in Read-only mode. Asks me to save a local copy to edit and it saves locally.

I have tried the following solutions and still it doesn't work:

- [Changed excel setting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58215/excel-links-open-files-as-read-only-mode-how-to-change-this-to-edit-mode)
- [I do not have KB3055034 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387931/cant-open-office-documents-from-sharepoint-site)
- [Deactivated](https://it.stonybrook.edu/help/kb/viewing-and-editing-sharepoint-documents-in-the-web-browser) "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" to open documents in the Web App to edit documents in the browser by default

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Is it happening in all browser? Have you configured excel service application?

Comment: @lovethakker I have checked in chrome and IE. It is occurring in both. Could you pls explain what you mean by excel service application? (windows server services/ SP farm services/ any other)

Comment: yes, excel service application in SharePoint farm. Also please let us know if you have checkout required settings enabled in library?

Comment: @lovethakker Excel services is enabled in the farm. Checkout required is enabled in the library.

Comment: Can you try with checkout not required?

Comment: From what i know, Sharepoint 2013 standard edition does not allow browser editing.